# segmentation fault (core dumped) - unable to findout where ive failed

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

i've been trying to clone a guessing game program for a while . i have very little experience in c. i've searched this error and read about it. i have understood the basic issue here. but i couldnt relate it to my programe here . i couldnt see any mistake here. can you help me please

`segmentation fault (core dumped)`  - this is the error i'm getting

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

  int snum = 7;
  int guess;
  int guesscount = 0;
  int guesslimit = 3;
  int outofguesses = 0;
  while (guess != snum && outofguesses == 0) {
    if (guesscount < guesslimit) {
      printf(" Enter the number : ");
      scanf("%d \n", guess);
      guesscount++;

    } else {
      outofguesses = 1;
    }
  }

  if (outofguesses == 1) {
    printf("You have failed dude");
  } else {
    printf("Congrats man you won ");

  }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d \n", guess);` should be `scanf("%d \n", &guess);`.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: @FiddlingBits thanks it's running now. but need more fix . btw why does all poeple downvote my question ? is there some issue with my question ?

Comment: @MartinVéronneau i'm running it on terminal . some random guy once told me to use the terminal instead of ide

Comment: @AbhishekN only one person (not me) downvoted your question. Probably because you haven't tried to debug it.

Comment: @AbhishekN Running on the terminal doesn't rule out using a debugger at all. I have no idea how you're set up, but if you're building with gcc, you can use gdb.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau yed i'm using gcc. i'll look forward using a debugger alongside it

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a segmentation fault means that you are trying to access memory that you are not supposed to access.

In your case, you are trying to `scanf` directly into a variable, whereas `scanf` takes an address. Try using an ampersand (`&`) with `guess`.

Comment: thanks . i kept repeating this same mistake. i learned the basics with python. i'm kinda confused with all these syntaxes

Comment: It's an incredibly common mistake, so don't feel too bad about it. Keep practicing, learn more about memory allocation and pointers, which makes C different from very high level languages like Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the line

```cpp
      scanf("%d \n", guess);
```

You have to pass `scanf` a memory address (pointer to a variable) to write into. (`&guess`)

But you pass it an integer (`guess`) which C/C++ interpretes as a memory address.

If `guess` equals `1337`, then `scanf` tries to write into memory address `0x539` (hexadecimal for `1337`).

Change the line into

```cpp
      scanf("%d \n", &guess);
```

and you'll be fine.

Comment: There is no default value for stack variables.

Comment: @FiddlingBits didnt know that myself. Thanks for that. I'll rewrite my answer. My basic message is still correct, I guess